# PHP JSON_ENCODE array doesn't return any response

Tags: php, json

I have a simple PHP script which queries the database and is supposed to return a JSON response but it doesn't seem to be working.

On `var_dump($players)` here is a sample response

```
array (size=99301)
 0 => 
array (size=2)
  'guid' => string '?B937097' (length=8)
  'name' => string '�scar Benito (?B937097)' (length=23)
 1 => 
array (size=2)
  'guid' => string '?D841077' (length=8)
  'name' => string '�ngel Luis Diez Samper (?D841077)' (length=33)
 2 => 
array (size=2)
  'guid' => string '?N573092' (length=8)
  'name' => string '�lvaro Negredo (?N573092)' (length=25)
 3 => 
array (size=2)
  'guid' => string '?V565877' (length=8)
  'name' => string '�lvaro V�zquez Garc�a (?V565877)' (length=32)
 4 => 
array (size=2)
  'guid' => string 'AA101850' (length=8)
  'name' => string 'Andrew Ansen (AA101850)' (length=23)
 5 => ....
```

and here is the PHP script. No errors are thrown but no response is returned in JSON format.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

require_once("db_config.php");

$conn = mysqli_connect(DBSERVER, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);

if(!$conn) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging erron: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

$players = array();

$sql = "SELECT DataGuid, DataField1, DataField2 FROM data_1";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if($query) {
    while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $players[] = array(
            'guid' => $res['DataGuid'],
            'name' => $res['DataField1'] . " " . $res['DataField2'] . " (" . $res['DataGuid'] . ")"
        );
    }   
}
else {
    echo "Error.";
}

mysqli_close($conn);

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($players);
```

I feel I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Probably there is a problem with coding. json_encode can work only with proper UTF8 characters

Comment: @nospor I've checked the database `data_1` and it has a `UTF-8` collation

Comment: Put some echos in the loops and ifs and load the page directly and see what you get.

Comment: @WebDevDanno the characters with the questionmark � indicate broken UTF characters.

Comment: But data can be wrongly read from db. We can see this in your print you showed us. You need after connection set connection as utf8 too

Comment: Try `json_encode($players, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)`

Comment: Try json_encode($players, 1)